# How to inline DataTemplate of a nested property?

Tags: wpf, binding

Suppose I have:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public string Id;
    // ...
}

<DataTemplate DataType="local:Employee"> ... </DataTemplate>
```

and:

```
class Manager
{
    public string Salary;
    public int Rank;
    public Employee DirectReport;
}
```

How would I write a `DataTemplate` for `Manager` while referencing the `Employee` `DataTemplate`?

i.e.:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="local:Manager">
   <TextBlock Text={Binding Salary}/>
   <TextBlock Text={Binding Rank}/>
   // How do I display the DirectReport here using Employee's DataTemplate?

</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this with simple OO inhertance rather than anything tricky with WPF.

A `Manager` is still an `Employee`, so change up your classes like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public string Id;
    public string Salary;
    Employee DirectReport;
    // ...
}

public class Manager : Employee
{   
    public int Rank;   
}
```

Then you can leave your WPF DataTemplate as it is.

Alternatively you can reference the EmployeeTemplate definition from within the ManagerTemplate by using a [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="local:Manager">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Salary}/>
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Rank}/>

    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeTemplate}" /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Other useful references are:

- [Using one data template in another data template in
  WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4664986/109702)
- [Is there a way
  to use data-template inheritance in
  WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4443600/109702)

Comment: Thanks, but in my scenario inheritance isn't really suitable. What I'm struggling with is displaying compound objects that hold properties of compound objects. Instead of writing one huge DataTemplate I was hoping that I could write multiple small ones and reference them